# plotting 3D plot at matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I want to plot a 3D figure of the electric field of an  antenna suspended with a variable height "h" from the ground.
I wrote the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
%% Simulation for an lamda/2 antenna suspended with a height from distance group with a variable h

%% Plotting: electrif field, radiated power, intensity and directivity in 3D
clc
clear all
close all hidden

%% Defining givens:
f= 300e6; %% Chosen frequency
c= 3e8; %% Free space
lambda= c./f; %% Wavelenght
l_2=lambda./2;
k= (2.*pi)./l_2; %% Wave number
Io=5; % Chosen maximum value of the current 
eighta=377; % Intrinsic impedance (free space)
r=l_2/(2.*pi); % Distance 
h= 0:1:100; %% Variable height from the ground
L=1.25*l_2; % Dipole length
theta= 2*pi;

%% Computing the requirements:

%% Electric field:
A= (k.*L.*Io.*exp(-1i.*r.*k))./(4.*pi.*r);
B= 2.*(cos(cos(theta).*k.*h));
E_F= eighta.*1i.*(A).*sin(theta).*(B);
[x,y,z]=sph2cart(h,theta,E_F); % Converting to cartesian coordinates

% Generating 3D plot
surf(x,y,z)
colormap(JET);
title ('Electric Field in 3D plot')
legend ('Heigth','Theta','Electric Field')
rotate3D on
axis image
```

I seem to be getting this error:

```
??? Error using ==> surf at 78
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.
```

Comment: Next time format code properly in the question

Comment: sorry I'm very new posting questions and stuff but thanks for telling me and editing my code properly. I really appreciated ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

besides what NKN mentioned in his answer. 
I'd guess you missed the correct definition of `theta`. It's just a scalar, I'd guess it should be a vector.

e.g.:
 `theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100)`

Then create a mesh of `theta` and `h`

```
[h,theta]=meshgrid(h,theta)
```

and do you calculation of `E_F`.

Probably you need to create meshes of `A` and `B` as well.

Finally you get a `Z`-matrix instead of a vector and `surf` is working properly. Maybe you should also consider `quiver`.

Comment: thanks for your reply but when I tried using theta as you mentioned, it gives an error that matix dimension should agree :( what do you suggest I do about it ?

Comment: Of course you get this error, but you need to rethink your whole code. It can't be answered with some lines. I even think that you also need a variable `r` - but I'm not sure. It's absolutely unclear what you actually want to plot. Add the moment your code is just dependent on `h` - that's not enough, right?

Comment: well actually what you suggested worked :D...I only needed to add the meshgriid to the h and theta and not A and B, furthermore the vector which you suggested also worked :D..now I'm getting my 3D plots :D...what I'm trying to plot is the Electric Field, directivity, power radiated and intensity of an antenna suspended from a heigth "h"..my code had to be dependent on both "h" and "theta" and thanks to you I was able of plotting them :D..thanks again for your help and fast replies :D

Answer (score 0):

Contour/surf commands usually work with two vectors (X and Y) and a matrix (Z). So for each elements of the two vectors (X(i) , Y(i)), there should be a value in the matrix (Z(i,j)). Thus the size of the matrix Z should be equal to the size of the first vector (X) multiplied by the size of the second vector (Y). 
according to matlab: surf(Z) creates a three-dimensional shaded surface from the z components in matrix Z, using x = 1:n and y = 1:m, where [m,n] = size(Z).

the first problem with your code is you are producing complex values inside the x,y,z which you cannot use with surf.

> Error using surf (line 75) X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex

if you remove/modify the imaginary part of the numbers then for example you can do something like this:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

although you can try:

```
plot3(x,y,z)
```